# IPhone X randomly crashing while in use

Tags: iphone, battery, crash

This started yesterday morning, and crashes about every 20 min or so of use, it was fine all night. And when it crashes, I get this red spike in battery performance.

What’s going on and how do I fix it, phone is out if AppleCare and I don't know if it'll make it two more weeks for the new phone.

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Can I ask what version of iOS you're running - both the version and build number. You can get this by looking at the Software Version label at Settings > General > About. If only a version number is visible, just tap on it to also get the build version (it'll appear in brackets).

Comment: Software version is 12.4.1 (16G102). It was doing it before a software update so I updated hoping it would solve it, but it did not

Comment: Thanks. Just this past week I've become aware of two other users experiencing the same issue, although not as regularly as every 20 mins - but that may depend on usage. Both have batteries in the 90% + health range that still support normal peak performance. One has the exact same version and build, but I won't know about the other for another 5 hrs, so am keen to see what version they're running. This is **purely speculative**, but I am wondering if there is some bug in that version that's affecting some users (although that's a pretty brave statement on the back of three devices).

Comment: 20 mins was the closest interval, I think I would say its once maybe every hour to two hours on average, it sort of depends on usage.

Comment: Well that fits with the others then - seems some apps are forcing the iPhone to crash more regularly, while others not at all, but on average every hour or so is what they're experiencing. I'll post another comment when I know about the other user's version and build. If it's the same I'll post feedback to Apple and ask them to do the same - just in case it's more than a coincidence.

Comment: Isolate what app / service is causing it by going to privacy > analytics > analytics data and look for the latest crash logs. It may be an app you downloaded, that can be solved by removing the app or waiting for an update.

Comment: I have the latest crash panic log, from last night, not sure what to look for in it, but it does not seem to mention anything about a specific app

Comment: Have you seen the settings-> battery -> battery health for performance vs stability options? Which one of them is enabled? (notify people using @<username> one person per comment)

Comment: @ankiiiiiiii battery health is 89% and peak performance

Comment: Post the log crash log here after redaction. cc: @Theologin in case you didnt come back to check :) Chris: my username has 7 i , you wrote 8 :)

Comment: Have you tried Quitting all apps and restaring the device? This is what we advice to our customers for numerous issues and it works.

Comment: @NaveedAbbas yes many times

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would try [force quitting all of your open apps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330) and seeing if that solves the issue. It looks like 'HQ' in your list above is using quite a bit of battery.

If that fails, I would try a [force restart of your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios). Note this is different than a standard power on/off.

Also, please confirm there is [sufficient hard drive space on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201656). If you're low on space, really bizarre issues like random crashes can happen. I would suggest having a minimum of 10-15 GB.

If neither of the above suggestions apply, to rule out any hardware issue, I would still suggest taking your phone to the Genius Bar at Apple. You can [make a reservation](https://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/) even if you're out of warranty.

They will run a battery of tests on your phone (for free) to let you know what may be wrong with it, and if it is hardware related, will give you pricing on a repair. Apple unfortunately does not expose these hardware tests to the general public.

They also have some limited leeway to go above and beyond for Apple customers depending on the issue you're having with your product, so keep that in mind.

Comment: I ended up just ordering the new iphone, it appears to be logic board issue based on a quick diagnostic that was done at a local apple certified repair shop, appointments at the genius bar are insane here for some reason, next available at my apple store is tuesday and I didn't feel like waiting that long.  Either way it works fine if plugged in, just not if it's high usage on the battery.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a logic board issue. Have you ever seen your phone flash a solid color prior to the shutdowns? When it crashes/restarts, does it boot to the Apple Logo screen, or does it take you back to the screen you were on prior to the shutdown?

There is a specific log within Privacy > Analytics > Analytics Data that would indicate the logic board failure. Send a screen shot of this list & I can give you a better idea.